# Not iterative assign

Tags: r, data.table

I am discovering the data.table and I came across an iterative problem. I am trying to create a new column which will count the number of successive times a value equals the one from the precedent row.

For example, with the data.table **a**:

```
   a
   V1 V2
1:  1  1
2:  2  1
3:  3  2
4:  4  2
5:  5  2
```

I would like to create a third column which will show how many successive times column V2 equals previous row in column V2:

```
   a
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  1  0
2:  2  1  1
3:  3  2  0
4:  4  2  1
5:  5  2  2
```

I can do this with a for, but for big data.tables it takes forever. **Can I do faster it using joins, .I, .SD or something specific to data.table?**

For now I am using a simple sequential C style loop programming:

```
a[,V3:=0]
for (i in 2:nrow(a))
{
  if (a[i,V2]==a[i-1,V2]) a[i,V3 := a[i-1,V3] + 1]
}
```

What I cannot do is transform it in vector style programming.

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Please show your `for` loop.

Comment: Roland, I update my initial question with the code for the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this what you need?

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(read.table(text="1  1
2  1
3  2
4  2
5  2"))

#put values not different from the preceding value in same group:
DT[, g:=cumsum(c(1,diff(V2)!=0))]

#create sequences by groups
DT[, V3:=seq_len(.N)-1, by=g]
#   V1 V2 g V3
#1:  1  1 1  0
#2:  2  1 1  1
#3:  3  2 2  0
#4:  4  2 2  1
#5:  5  2 2  2
```